# Deleting Cluster in GCP failed with message "resource is not ready"

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I delete cluster from **GCP** it not deleting at all and failed with a message

> Google Compute Engine: The resource `cluster_name-e7234567` is not
>   ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Google Kubernetes Engine**

40-80% of `Compute Engine API` operations may have become stuck pending if submitted during Nov 1 and 2. This is due GCP compute engine failure.
To determine whether you are affected by this incident, you may run the following command [1] `gcloud compute operations list --filter="status!=DONE”` to view your project’s pending operations.

This was a GCP issue and they have fixed it. Here you can check the status of this issue https://status.cloud.google.com//incident/compute/19008?_ga=2.34100449.-1979053317.1572500365